# Re-indexing a column with either SQL or PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have several tables that use an ID number plus a column called `xsequence` that are both primary keys.  Currently, I have a bunch of data that looks like this:

```
ID_NUMBER,XSEQUENCE
001,2
001,5
001,8
002,1
002,6
```

What I need to end up with is:

```
ID_NUMBER,XSEQUENCE
001,1
001,2
001,3
002,1
002,2
```

What is the best way of going about starting this?  Every time I try, I just end up spinning my wheels.

Comment: You mean it's a composite primary key using both columns? Presumably you need to update related foreign key values too. But do you really need to do this - does the actual value matter? Or looking at it another way, do you need to actually update the value, or would a query/view that makes the sequence look contiguous be enough?

Comment: We are thinking they need to be sequential order because they are messing with updates that we try to do.

Comment: Sounds like you might be trying to solve the wrong problem then. Particularly if future changes (deletes) would introduce gaps again. Perhaps you could explain your original problem and why you think making them contiguous would help; though that would probably be a very different question of course.

Comment: I think you are correct.  We feel the solution is to get rid of the composite primary key, but the product we are using is a deliverable from another vendor.  We've been told to avoid changes to the delivered code.

Comment: I agree with Alex. Even if re-sequencing solved your problem, it is a temporary solution at best. I cannot think how having a composite PK is messing up updates. I would love to see more detail on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select id_number,
       row_number() over (partition by id_number order by xsequence) new_xsequence
  from yourtable
```

That's an analytic function really handy for this sort of thing. Using the Partition keyword - "resets" the counter at each id_number. (so 1,2,3 .. then starts again 1,2,3 ... etc.).

(The Partition keyword in analytic functions behaves very similar to the GROUP by keyword)

[edit]
To UPDATE the original table, I actually prefer the MERGE statement - it's a bit simpler syntax wise, and seems a bit more intuitive ;) )

```
  MERGE INTO yourtable  base
     USING (
              select rowid   rid,
                     id_number,
                     row_number() over (partition by id_number order by xsequence) new_xsequence,
                     xsequence   old_xsequence
                from yourtable
           ) new
     ON ( base.rowid = new.rid )
     WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
        SET base.xsequence = new.new_xsequence
```

[edit]

Comment: That works perfect!  Now how could I incorporate that into an update statement?

Comment: `UPDATE (select id_number,
       row_number() over (partition by id_number order by xsequence) new_xsequence
  from yourtable) SET xsequence = new_xsequence;`

Comment: That's not working.  I'm getting this error:  [Error] Execution (14: 35): ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: "BASE"."XSEQUENCE"

Comment: @jacob: Oh, ok, in that case, try my lastest edit.  Use "rowids" to link back to the original ... I use that trick to bypass that error often.